# Can I get information other people's (Apple) bug reports?

Tags: report, apple-radar

Others have said Apple's bug-tracking system only allows you to see bug reports you yourself have filed. (See [Can I browse other people's (Apple) bug reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports).)

But I keep seeing comments in various developer forums (such as xcode-users) along the lines of "I'm fairly sure this is a dup of < rdar://problem/7715072>".

How do they know? Does this mean they must have filed that bug report themselves?

And what use are such comments if no one else can see what that bug report says? (I checked, this one is not on OpenRadar http://openradar.appspot.com/.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I browse other people's (Apple) bug reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports)

Comment: Yes, I've long since come to terms w/ Apple policy on this, and I am aware (and refer to) OpenRadar when it might be helpful. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion apple is not sharing the bugs (a) due to security issues and (b) to get the people report bugs even if they are duplicated.  In that way the reported bugs with the most reports will jump up in the priority and will eventually be solved faster.

> How do they know? Does this mean they must have filed that bug report themselves?

Yes, I think so. If you file a bug which already has been filed before by others, apple will mark your bug being a duplicate and close it with an advice to follow the original bug id.

Answer (score 0):

If the 1st statement is true, and you can't browse someone else's bugs, there are two possibilities:

1. apple developers can see them
2. they filled these bugs

Comment: Yes, my comment was more along the lines of "if people are saying 'this is a duplicate of rdar such-and-such', doesn't that imply they expect others to be able to look up that bug and see how it relates to the issue they're discussing?" Which would suggest those who say Apple's bug database is closed to outsiders are wrong. Otherwise the simple statement that 'this bug duplicates rdr such-and-such' is completely useless to anyone who is not an Apple employee with access to that database.